# Using or not using Gin or Gist index in PostgreSQL, make no differences?

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, query-performance

### Question:

Here are about 50 millions rows data, and i would like use PostgreSQL to manage that. The main purpose is text serching, it usually takes several minutes to get the results, and i wondering if PG's trigram indexes is the solution for speed that up.

But after i create the pg_trgm extension, create (gist/gin) index for certain column, and query, the query is not faster than not using none of indexes.

I wondering if i'm using it the right way. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

### Environment:

```
OS: Windows 10 x64
HDD: 1TB
RAM: 8GB, 1600MHz
CPU: Intel Core i5-4460, 3.2GHz
PostgreSQL: 9.6
```

### Procedure:

Here is the procedure in psql terminal:

**1. install the extension:**

```
 $ create extension pg_trgm;
```

**2. normal search:**

```
$ explain (analyze,buffers) select * from tbl_sample where hr_name
like '%ojan%';

QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on tbl_sample  (cost=0.00..4629896.15 rows=19053316 width=506) (actual time=1.491..171900.251 rows=18623285 loops=1)
  Filter: ((hr_name)::text ~~ '%ojan%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 37999208
  Buffers: shared hit=2830 read=3919285
Planning time: 0.101 ms
Execution time: 172525.172 ms
```

**3. gist search:**

```
$ create index hr_name_gist_idx on tbl_sample using gist (hr_name
gist_trgm_ops);

time:5513539ms

$ explain (analyze,buffers) select * from tbl_sample where hr_name
like '%ojan%';

QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on tbl_sample  (cost=0.00..4629896.15 rows=19053316 width=506) (actual time=58.490..172845.089 rows=18623285 loops=1)
  Filter: ((hr_name)::text ~~ '%ojan%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 37999208
  Buffers: shared read=3922115
 Planning time: 66.508 ms
 Execution time: 173668.369 ms
```

**4. gin search:**

```
$ drop index hr_name_gist_idx;
$ create index hr_name_gin_idx on tbl_sample using gin (hr_name
gin_trgm_ops);

time: 476069ms

$ expalin (analyze,buffers) select * from tbl_sample where hr_name
like '%ojan%';

QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_sample  (cost=175607.20..4335888.65 rows=19053316 width=506) (actual time=6385.809..179910.643 rows=18623285 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((hr_name)::text ~~ '%ojan%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 32648417
  Heap Blocks: exact=18691 lossy=3554283
  Buffers: shared hit=3664 read=3578519
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on hr_name_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..170843.87 rows=19053316 width=0) (actual time=6353.253..6353.253 rows=18623285 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((hr_name)::text ~~ '%ojan%'::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=3664 read=5545
Planning time: 20.645 ms
Execution time: 180633.642 ms
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the actual execution plans instead of just the runtime. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Apparently, your condition is not really selective - it seems to keep one row out of three.  This is hard to support with indexes, and as you noticed, all three queries check basically the whole table.

Comment: @dezso thanks for answering, what's the least number of characters in query condition to support with indexes?

Comment: It's not the number of characters in itself - it is the portion of rows that your query would return.  There is no real rule, but if it is down to 10%, for example, you already have better chances.  (Of course, if you add some more characters, it might match a smaller part of the table.)  In this very case, I cannot imagine what you would do with all those millions of rows, so there might be a way to make the result set smaller.